# Asynchronous loading of Google Map Markers from Json data

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

Currently I'm loading a map with a few hundred markers. This works great for just a few properties. However when I try to load many markers the page freezes while loading the data.

Inside of my initialize function I'm loading the map and creating the markers.

```
var map;
var markers = [];

function initialize(id) {

    // setup the map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    // wait for loaded and add markers
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {
        if (checkevent == false) {
            createPropertyMarkers(); // add the markers
        }            
    });
}
// end map
```

With this function I add the markers.

```
// create the property markers
function createPropertyMarkers() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    //alert(bounds);

    // loop through the json and get property data
    for (var i = 0; i < markersdata.d.length; ++i) {
        // set marker zindex
        var zindex = 1;

        // set the marker position
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(markersdata.d[i].lat,
            markersdata.d[i].lon);

        // set icon for property
        var micon = '/images/home-2.png';
        if (markersdata.d[i].count > 0) {
            micon = '/images/home.png';
        }

        // set the main proerty marker to blue.
        if (GetQueryStringParams('id') == markersdata.d[i].id) {
            micon = '/images/homeBlue.png';
            zindex = 10;
        }

        // drop the marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            title: markersdata.d[i].address,
            zIndex: zindex,
            icon: micon
        });
        // set the marker 
        iwcontent = '<div id=\"content\" style=\"margin: 5px ; padding: 0; width: 220px; min-height: 250px;\">' +
            '<h2 id=\"firstHeading\" class=\"firstHeading\" style=\"margin: -5px 0 1px 0; padding: 0;\">Property</h2>' +
            '<div id=\"bodyContent\">' +
            '<img src=\"/images/ajax-loader.gif\" alt=\"wait\" style=\"margin: 5px 0; padding: 0;\" /><br /><h3>Loading Info</h3><br /><br /><br /></div>' +
            '<div id=\"propertyentityinfo\">' +
            '</div></div>'
        ;

        // add listener to open marker infowindow
        attachListener(marker, iwcontent, markersdata.d[i].id);
        // push markers to array
        markers.push(marker);

        //document.getElementById("testResults").innerHTML += i + " " + bounds.toString() + " - " + markersdata.d[i].lat + "," + markersdata.d[i].lon + " <br />";
    }
    // end loop
}

// load property markers
markersdata = getPropertyMarkers(GetQueryStringParams('id'));
```

Here I add the on click listener for the icons that will open up the infowindow and display data.

```
// add the listener to the property markers
function attachListener(marker, content, id) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
        //infowindow.close();
        checkevent = true;
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        infowindow.open(map, this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            loadPropertyInfo(id); // load infowindow data
            checkevent = false;
        }, 1000);
        //setTimeout('checkevent = false', 3000);
    });
}
```

Now here's the issue. In my function that gets the json data from my webservice. I'm using async: false in order to get this to work. If I take that out the markers will not load. However when set to false it also causes the webpage to wait until the data comes in.

How can I modify my code to get this to work async?

```
// get markers for loading
function getPropertyMarkers(propertyid) {
var mydata;

$.ajax({
    url: "Service/MapData.asmx/getPropertyMarkers",
    type: "POST",
    data: "{'id': '" + propertyid + "'}",
    async: false, <----------------- THE PROBLEM!
    cache: true,
    contentType: "application/json;",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { //
        mydata = data;
        //initialize(propertyid);
    },
    error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
        alert("Screen shot this error: " + xmlHttpRequest.toString() + " " + textStatus.toString() + " " + errorThrown.toString());
    }
});
return mydata;
}
```

Comment: Your code is calling functions that do not exist. Did you forget to post them?

Comment: I removed them. they aren't part of the issue.

Comment: Where is _getPropertyMarkers()_ called?

Comment: it's called right after the function. the script works as intended. 
Except when I change the async false to true.

Comment: The problem is that this function returns `mydata` as undefined. That is due to the ajax not firing its success callback (it does not have the data from server yet).

Comment: call the `createPropertyMarkers` function in the callback for your JSON request (the "success" function)

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. I'll need to modify my code a bit to get things working right. But that is the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call the `createPropertyMarkers` function in the callback for your JSON request (the "success" function), I would suggest passing the returned json into that function rather than (or in addition to) making it global.

```
// get markers for loading
function getPropertyMarkers(propertyid) {
  var mydata;

  $.ajax({
    url: "Service/MapData.asmx/getPropertyMarkers",
    type: "POST",
    data: "{'id': '" + propertyid + "'}",
    async: true,
    cache: true,
    contentType: "application/json;",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { //
        mydata = data;
        createPropertyMarkers(); 
        //initialize(propertyid);
    },
    error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
        alert("Screen shot this error: " + xmlHttpRequest.toString() + " " + textStatus.toString() + " " + errorThrown.toString());
    }
  });
}
```